# Accounting for missing array keys, within PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm parsing a document for several different values, with PHP and Xpath. I'm throwing the results/matches of my Xpath queries into an array. So for example, I build my `$prices array` like this:

```
$prices = array();
$result = $xpath->query("//div[@class='the-price']");
foreach ($result as $object) {
$prices[] = $object->nodeValue; }
```

Once I have my array built, I loop through and throw the values into some HTML like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo <<<EOF
<div class="the-product">
    <div class="the-name"><a title="{$names[$i]}" href="{$link}" target="blank">{$names[$i]}</a></div>
    <br />
    <div class="the-image"><a title="{$names[$i]}" href="{$link}" target="blank"><img src="{$images[$i]}" /></a></div>
    <br />
    <div class="the-current-price">Price is: <br> {$prices[$i]}</div>
</div>
EOF;
    $i++; }
```

The problem is, some items in the original document that I'm parsing don't have a price, as in, they don't even contain `<div class='the-price'>`, so my Xpath isn't finding a value, and isn't inserting a value into the `$prices array`. I end up returning **20** products, and an array which contains only **17** keys/values, leading to `Notice: Undefined offset` errors all over the place.

So my question is, how can I account for items that are missing key values and throwing off my arrays? Can I insert dummy values into the array for these items? I've tried as many different solutions as I can think of. Mainly, IF statements within my foreach loops, but nothing seems to work.

Thank you

Comment: Presumably in your 17/20 scenario, its the last 3 which are empty so making most of the previous ones show incorrect prices, is this the case?

Comment: In that scenario, yes that is the case. But there could be any scenario with X out of 20 products have a missing price. And these products could be anywhere within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look for an element inside your html which is always present in your "price"-loop. After you find this object you start looking for the "price" element, if there is none, you insert an empty string, etc. into your array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly looking for the `the-price` elements, look for the containing `the-product`. Loop on those, then do a subquery using those nodes as the starting context. That way you get all of the `the-product` nodes, plus the prices for those that have them.

e.g.

```
$products = array();
$products = $xpath->query("//div[@class='the-product']");
$found = 0 ;
foreach ($products as $product) {
   $products[$found] = array();
   $price = $xpath->query("//div[@class='the-price']", $product);
   if ($price->length > 0) {
       $products[$found] = $price->item(0)->nodeValue;
   }
   $found++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. Unfortunately this is returning a fatal error for me - 'Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array'

Comment: Oops. misused `$products` in there as the final array and the results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show the products that don't have a price attached to them you could check if `$prices[$i]` is set first.

```
foreach($links AS $link){
    if(isset($prices[$i])){
        // echo content
    }
}
```

Or if you wanted to fill it will dummy values you could say

```
$prices = array_merge($prices,
              array_fill(count($prices), count($links)-count($prices),0));
```

And that would insert `0` as a dummy value for any remaining values. `array_fill` starts off by taking the first index of the array (so we start one after the amount of keys in `$prices`), then how many we need to fill, so we subtract how many are in `$prices` from how many are in `$links`, then we fill it with the dummy value 0.

Alternatively you could use the same logic in the first example and just apply that by saying:

```
echo isset($prices[$i]) ? $prices[$i] : '0';
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I DO still want to show products with missing prices, and ideally, represent them with a dummy value, within my $prices array. Your last block of code seems to work, but it appears to just marge the dummy '0' values at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand the relation between $links and $prices with the code shown. Since you are building the $prices array without any relation to the $links array, I don't see how you would do this.

Is $links also built via xpath? If so, is 'the-price' div always nested within the DOM element used to populate $links?

If it is you could nest your xpath query to find the price within the query used to find the links and use a counter to match the two.

i.e.

```
$links_result = $xpath->query('path-to-link')
$i = 0
foreach ($links_result as $link_object) {
    $links[$i] = $link_object->nodeValue;
    // pass $link_object as context reference to xpath query looking for price
    $price_result = $xpath->query('path-to-price-within-link-node', $link_object);
    if (false !== $price_result) {
        $prices[$i] = $price_result->nodeValue;
    } else {
        $prices[$i] = 0; // or whatever value you want to show to indicate that no price was available.
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Obviously, there could be additional handling in there to verify that only one price value exists per link node and so forth, but that is basic idea.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the answer. $links IS also built via Xpath. But 'the-price' div is NOT always nested within that same DOM element. For the products that are missing prices, that div simply doesn't exist.

Comment: That is fine if they are alwasy nested if present, this code should work.  If the 'the-price' div does not exist, the $price_result value reutrned from the xpath query will be false, in which cases you know to simply add a $prices[$i] = 0 or whatever value you want to add to indicate there is no price for the item.

Comment: Thanks Mike... going to give this a shot.